# ICE32 Error from MSM

Tags: installation, wix, wix3, merge-module

I have 4 MSM's that are needed for one of my products and they are all producing ICE32 errors when included.  This would normally not bother me cause they are external errors and I still get my MSI and it works perfectly.  The problem arrises though, that I can not request help from Microsoft with ANY issues that arise from this particular setup project if there are ICE errors (like good ole 32).  Interesting side note is that the MSM's causing the errors are Microsoft modules.

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of these errors short of editing the MSM files directly?

I have tried using EnsureTable element to no avail, and it is only these four MSM's that are used so I can't even try placing another merge module before them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just ensuring the wrong tables.  In total I had to ensure the Class, PublishComponent, Condition, TypeLib, and Extension tables in order to take care of the errors given to me by the VC_User MSM's from Microsoft.  Hope this can help someone else find the problem a little more quickly.